# ADF - Error using View Object

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am trying to programmatically use a View Object to select/update/insert rows.  The class being used does not directly use a Data Control, just the ViewObjectImpl directly.

So when I get to the following line:

```
    RowSetIterator rowSet = vo.createRowSetIterator(null);
```

The following exception is thrown:

javax.servlet.ServletException: JBO-25036: An invalid object operation was invoked on type View Object with name

Can a View Object Impl class be used without the data control?

Answer (score 0):

This is valid code that should work with any VO:

```
RowSetIterator rowSet = vo.createRowSetIterator(null);
```

The fact that it doesn't it it points towards a problem with the VO definition itself.

Try querying that VO from BC Tester, see if it works.